# Re-Render (root-)Layout in NextJs 13 (with app directory) after navigation?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, layout

My root layout contains the navigation which I want to display on every page and the children props for child pages/layouts:

```
export default function RootLayout({children}: {children: React.ReactNode}) {
return (
  <html lang="en">
    <head />
    <body>
      <Navbar isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} />
      <maina>
        {children}
      </main>
    </body>
  </html>
)
```

The *Navbar* contains links like *sign up*, *sign in* and *logout* which I want to display conditionally. After sign up or sign in, the client redirects to the home page via router.push('/') and sends a JWT token.

I want the `isLoggedIn()` function in the root layout to be executed again but according to the NextJs documentation, layouts don't re-render and keep state.

How can I notify layouts that the state (user is logged in/logged out) changed?

Answer (score 7):

You can call `router.refresh()` right after calling `router.push('/')`. For example:

```js
const handleSignUp = () => {
    router.push('/');
    router.refresh();
};
```

This way, the page will be refreshed. Here's a link to [Next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router#userouter:%7E:text=history%20stack.-,router.refresh(),-%3A%20Refresh%20the%20current).